# Merge two data in @Html.DisplayFor in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to Merge this two dislpay

```
  <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>  item.CustomerFirstName)
  </td>
  <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerLastName)
  </td>
```

into like this

```
  <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerFirstName && item.CustomerLastName )
  </td>
```

Comment: You cant. Either add a property to your view model that concatenates both values or put the 2 x `DisplayFor()` in the same `<td>` element

Comment: My model is from SDK so I can't modify it

Comment: That's why we use view models

Comment: if your model had something formatted on a particular field then `Html.DisplayFor(...)` comes in handy (e.g. `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]`). In this case though (and as you can't/don't want to edit the model) why not just have: `<td>@item.CustomerFirstName @item.CustomerLastName</td>`

Answer (score 8):

Use code block to concatenate the first name and last name then pass result to DisplayFor as shown below.

```
 <tr>
    <td>
    @{
        var fullName = Model.CustomerFirstName + " " + Model.CustomerLastName;
        @Html.DisplayFor(m=>fullName)
    }
    </td>
 </tr>
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

We can write like

@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName), @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer, no you can't do that.

If you can't modify it from the SDK, use ViewModels, map the SDK entities to your ViewModels and merge firstname and lastname together in your controller before passing it to the view.

View Model:

```
public class YourViewModel
{
     public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult YourController()
{
    var model = new YourViewModel {
        FullName = FirstName + LastName //from your SDK
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

Then you can do this in your View:

```
@model xxx.YourViewModel

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FullName)
```

Or, why don't you just do this?

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerFirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerLastName)</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always for something like this:

```
<label>@Html.Raw(string.format("{0},{1}",Model.CustomerFirstNAme,Model.CustomerLastNAme))</label>
```